# Assigning state to a nested array with ReactJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I am currently trying to assign `state` to a nested object using the hook `setState()` but I'm struggling a little bit with figuring out the syntax and how exactly I am supposed to do it.

I have structured my component like this:

```
const MainCard = props =>{

       const passedState = props.location.state;

     return(
          <div className="main-container">
             <div className="row">
               <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <AttendeeCard passedState={passedState} />
               </div>
               <div className="col-md-6 col-lg-6">
                    <AttendeeCard passedState={passedState} />
               </div>
             </div>
          </div>
   )
}

export default withRouter(MainCard)
```

So the props received from `location` are the data that I'll be passing to the `AttendeeCard` component.

Here is the data I'm [passing down the component.](http://myjson.com/1cr9pa)

I have structured my `AttendeeCard` component the following way:

```
  const AttendeeCard = props =>{

            const students= props.passedState.students;
            const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);

            const checkInStudent= () =>{
               setIsChecked(!isChecked);
            }


        return(
             students.map((student,i)=>{
                 return(
                      <div className="studentCard">
                          <div className="checkinput">
                              <input type="checkbox" 
                                  onChange={checkInStudent}
                                  checked value={isChecked}/>
                               <span className="slider round"></span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  )
             })

     )
   }
```

So instead of using `const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(false);` to assign one state to all checkboxes, I'd like to assign each `checkedin` state corresponding to the users.

I've tried  writing something like:

```
       students.map((student,i)=>{
             const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(student.checkedin);

           return(
                      <div className="studentCard">
                          <div className="checkinput">
                              <input type="checkbox" 
                                  onChange={checkInStudent}
                                  checked value={isChecked}/>
                               <span className="slider round"></span>
                          </div>
                      </div>
                  )
             })
       })
```

but I got an error and it didn't compile.

How can I assign state for each of the `checkedin` nested objects per student in my array?

UPDATE:

The error I get whenever I try the code above is:

> React Hook "useState" cannot be called inside a callback. React Hooks
>   must be called in a React function component or a custom React Hook
>   function  react-hooks/rules-of-hooks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the rules of React hooks is [don't call hooks inside loops](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-at-the-top-level). You can instead move your code into a new component and call the hook inside the component:

```js
function StudentCard({ checkedIn }) {
  const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(checkedIn);
  const checkInStudent = () => {
    setIsChecked(!isChecked);
  };

  return (
    <div className="studentCard">
      <div className="checkinput">
        <input
          type="checkbox"
          onChange={checkInStudent}
          checked
          value={isChecked}
        />
        <span className="slider round"></span>
      </div>
    </div>
  );;
}

const AttendeeCard = props => {
  const students = props.passedState.students;

  return students.map((student, i) => {
    return (
      <StudentCard
        checkedIn={student.checkedin}
        key={i}
      />
    );
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can make your code work by creating a new child component for the studentCard. So your code would be something like this :

```
const AttendeeCard = props =>{
    const students= props.passedState.students;

    return(
         students.map((student,i)=>{
             return(
                  <StudentCard student=student/>
              )
         })

 )
```

}

and StudentCard would be like this:

```
const StudentCard = props =>{
       const [isChecked, setIsChecked] = useState(props.student.checkedin);

       return(
                  <div className="studentCard">
                      <div className="checkinput">
                          <input type="checkbox" 
                              onChange={checkInStudent}
                              checked value={isChecked}/>
                           <span className="slider round"></span>
                      </div>
                  </div>
              )
}
```

By this way every StudentCard has it internal state and you can change it every time you want.

I hope it solves your problem. If it works please vote me up:)